# RabbitMQ : Difference between "message-ttl" and "expiration"

Tags: rabbitmq

What is the real difference between `expiration` and `message-ttl` in RabbitMQ?

I've read the documentation (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) but still isn't clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**message-ttl** is set on a queue. You can bind multiple exchanges to the same queue. All messages which are routed to the queue will get this **message-ttl** set. **expiration** is set on a message by the sender. If the message is routed to a queue which has a **message-ttl** the lower of both values is applied.